# How to create patterns in Python using nested loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I am trying to create this pattern in Python:

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```

I have to use a nested loop, and this is my program so far:

```
steps=6
for r in range(steps):
    for c in range(r):
        print(' ', end='')
    print('#')
```

The problem is the first column doesn't show up, so this is what is displayed when I run it:

```
#
 #
  #
   #
    #
     #
```

This is the modified program:

```
steps=6
for r in range(steps):
    print('#')
    for c in range(r):
        print(' ', end='')
    print('#')
```

but the result is:

```
#
  #
#
   #
#
    #
#
     #
#
      #
#
       #
```

How do I get them on the same row?

Comment: You are not printing any start at the begining of each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this...:

```
steps=6
for r in range(steps):
    for c in range(r):
        print(' ', end='')
    print('#')
```

With this:

```
steps=6
for r in range(steps):
    print('#', end='')
    for c in range(r):
        print(' ', end='')
    print('#')
```

Which outputs:

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```

It's just a simple mistake in the program logic.

However, it is still better to do this:

```
steps=6
for r in range(steps):
    print('#' + (' ' * r) + '#')
```

To avoid complications like this happening when using nested `for` loops, you can just use operators on the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Try this simpler method:

```
steps=6
for r in range(steps):
    print '#' + ' ' * r + '#'
```

Comment: Your program works perfectly, but I'm required to use a nested loop structure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the second print "#".  Put it before the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Try something like this:

`rows=int(input("Number"))
s=rows//2
for r in range(rows):
    print("#",end="")
print()
for r in range(rows):
    while s>=0:
        print("#"+" "*(s)+"#")
        s=s-1
    print("#")`

Comment: To get an inverse result