# Making a pattern in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, design-patterns, nested-loops

I do not know how to use loops in python and need help to make this pattern:

```
*
**
***
**** 
*****
```

This is what I have tried:

```
for x in range(0, 5):
  print ("*")
```

And the result is:

```
*
*
*
*
*
```

Comment: This pattern is not the one I am looking for.

Comment: there are several questions about just this topic, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287100/how-to-create-patterns-in-python-using-nested-loops - so just modify the answer found there

Comment: Please, my assingment is due soon, i am a beginner in programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step solution.

```
# for loop
for cnt in range(1,6):
    # print 'cnt' number of asterisks
    print(cnt * '*')
```

The result is:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: Or use the counter you already have... `for num in range(1,6): print('*' * num)`